# mvc3 jquery ajax post error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I've found a lot of posts about this error, but none of them helped, it seems that everybody else got this error in a different situation. But this is my first MVC project, so maybe I'm just not getting it :) So, I have a very simple ajax call:

```
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/MyMethod",
                data: ({ SomeProperty:"someValue" }),
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(obj.Status);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

and the very simple `MyMethod` controller method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddReport(MyModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.MyModels.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(...);
            }
            else
            {
                //not good...
            }
        }
```

the line `db.MyModels.Add(model);` triggers the error. I have another controller in an admin area that handles the CRUD operations for the same model, and it's working just fine. I know that probably the problem is that the `model` is already attached to the `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext` and I have to detach it, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the instance of your ObjectContext get instantiated? Usually this error indicates that Entity Framework thinks another ObjectContext already has a copy of that object it is tracking.

Are you disposing of you ObjectContexts after you use them, or storing on in the session for reuse? These types of problems can occur when you have multiple undisposed ObjectContexts for a same datasets.

Also see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/adodotnetentityframework/thread/501d7b99-0cb9-44b6-b2cd-16275a151b31 for some links.

Comment: I don't know what an ObjectContext is, or where it's instantiated. I had no idea that I'm using one. I already checked out that link, but it's not clear what I have to do.

Comment: ObjectContext is the db object you are using. Were does db object get created / assigned to in your code?

Comment: In the controller, `private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();`. It implements `DbContext` and has some `public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }`

Comment: I finally understood what's happening. In `MyModel`, that had an `AnotherModel` reference, I was instantiating the db again, because the `AnotherModelId` property of `MyModel` needs to be the latest `AnotherModel` and needed to get that. I'll instantiate the db only once, and store it in a session.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but from a different cause. I had a child collection in a new object that was being populated with a child that had been created in a different context like this:

```
User newUser = new User
{
    UserId = (Guid)user1.ProviderUserKey,
    Username = user1.UserName,
               ...
    AuthorizedOrgs = new List<Org> { currOrg }
};

context.Users.Add(newUser);
```

currOrg was causing the error since it had been instantiated in a different context.

Changing it to this solved the problem:

```
User newUser = new User
{
    UserId = (Guid)user1.ProviderUserKey,
    Username = user1.UserName,
               ...
    AuthorizedOrgs = new List<Org> { context.Orgs.Find(currOrg.Id) }
};

context.Users.Add(newUser);
```

As you can see, I retrieved the currOrg again from within the current context.